# Is there a way to remove sprites by their filename?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a small snippet of code that creates up to 21 instances of a certain sprite. After the user creates 21 sprites (by pressing a button), I want all the sprites to be removed from their parent. I hit a roadblock when I tried to remove the 21 sprites, because the way I created the sprites is I made a new instance of the sprite each time the user clicks the button.

```
-(void)createNewCactus
{
    CCSprite *newCactus = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"cactusclipart.png"];
    [newCactus setScale:0.25];
    if (cactiCount <= 21) {
        cactiCount++;
        if (cactiCount < 7)
            [newCactus setPosition:ccp(43*cactiCount, 140)];
        else if (cactiCount < 13)
            [newCactus setPosition:ccp(43*cactiCount-258, 90)];
        else
            [newCactus setPosition:ccp(43*cactiCount-516, 40)];
        [self addChild:newCactus];
    } else {
        [newCactus removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }
}
```

My question is, is there any way I can use cocos2d to remove all sprites by file name? Something like, `[self removeAllSpritesByFileName@"cactusclipart.png"];`? Would something like this even work considering I'm making a new instance for every sprite? In hindsight I realize that the way I wrote this code is probably not the best, but I'm stuck at trying to think of any other method that wouldn't be a colossal mess. Maybe a `for` loop with an NSArray?

Comment: not per say, but could be done ... what version of cocos2d are you using ?

Comment: im using version 3.0.0

Answer (score 3):

with 3.x ... use the name property of CCNode to your advantage.

```
-(void)createNewCactus
{
    CCSprite *newCactus = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"cactusclipart.png"];
    [newCactus setScale:0.25];
    newCactus.name = @"cactusclipart.png";
    if (cactiCount <= 21) {
        cactiCount++;
        if (cactiCount < 7)
            [newCactus setPosition:ccp(43*cactiCount, 140)];
        else if (cactiCount < 13)
            [newCactus setPosition:ccp(43*cactiCount-258, 90)];
        else
            [newCactus setPosition:ccp(43*cactiCount-516, 40)];
        [self addChild:newCactus];
    } else {
        [newCactus removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]; // <- this will never happen
    }
}
```

and to remove do something like :

```
CCSprite *cac;
while (cac = [self getChildByName:@"cactusclipart.png" recursively:NO]) {
   [cac revoveFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}
```

Comment: Alright, I placed the remove code under the `}else{` statement and put an NSLog inside the `while` loop. The NSLog wasn't outputted so for some reason `cac`'s name never is `@"cactusclipart.png`.

Comment: Got it working with an NSMutableArray. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

used an array

```
-(void)createNewCactus
{

    CCSprite *newCactus = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"cactusclipart.png"];
    [newCactus setScale:0.25];
    if (cactiCount < 18) {
        cactiCount++;
        if (cactiCount < 7)
            [newCactus setPosition:ccp(43*cactiCount, 140)];
        else if (cactiCount < 13)
            [newCactus setPosition:ccp(43*cactiCount-258, 90)];
        else if (cactiCount < 19)
            [newCactus setPosition:ccp(43*cactiCount-516, 40)];
        [self addChild:newCactus];
        NSLog(@"%li", (long)cactiCount);
        [spriteArray addObject:newCactus];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"should dlelete");
        for (int i = 0; i <= spriteArray.count-1; i++) {
            [spriteArray[i] removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
        }
    }
}
```